# Every commutative ring of characteristic $p$ contains $\mathbb F_p$ as a subring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rngs

I know that if a commutative ring *with unity* is of characteristic $p$ then it will contain $\mathbb F_p$ as a subring, but if the ring is commutative with characteristic $p$ and *without unity* then is it possible to find such a  map between the ring and $\mathbb Z$  such that we  can show that the ring contains $\mathbb F_p$ as a subring?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Consider, in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, the subring $R=\{\bar 0, \bar 2\}$.  Then it has characteristic $2$, but as a ring, it does not contain $\mathbb{F}_2$, since it has only two elements but no identity element.

Answer (score 4):

Another example would be the ideal $A=(X)$ in $F_p[X]$. It's a rng of characteristic $p$, but it can't contain $F_p$ since the only idempotent element is $0$.